# Composer dont init and update submodules

Tags: php, git, composer-php, packagist

I'm making a composer library that have the following structure

```
- vendor/
- src/
- data/
    - cnab/ (Submodule: contains files that can be reused in other projects)
- composer.json
```

However when I require my library in other project, submodules are not started and updated.

I tried to use composer scripts but no success:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "git submodule init",
        "git submodule update"
    ]
}
```